# React.js Namespaced Components show nothing

Tags: javascript, namespaces, reactjs

In the official document React.js, there is a new feature:Namespaced Components from version 0.11.

REF:http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

```
var Form = MyFormComponent;

var App = (
  <Form>
    <Form.Row>
      <Form.Label />
      <Form.Input />
    </Form.Row>
  </Form>
);

var MyFormComponent = React.createClass({ ... });
MyFormComponent.Row = React.createClass({ ... });
MyFormComponent.Label = React.createClass({ ... });
MyFormComponent.Input = React.createClass({ ... });
```

So, I refer it and write following code to create a component

```
var MysearchPage=React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
MysearchPage.Title=React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return (
      <h1>MysearchPage!</h1>
    );
  }
});
MysearchPage.Search= React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.searchType}:<input type="text"/>
        <button>Search</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var SearchPage=MysearchPage;

var App=(
    <SearchPage>
      <SearchPage.Title />
      <SearchPage.Search searchType="Content"/>
   </SearchPage>
);
React.render(
  App,
  document.getElementById('nuno')
);
```

***Finally,there is no error message,but it show nothing and I cannot see result.I want to know why it show nothing and where is error.***

I guess "SearchPage.Title" node do not append to "SearchPage".
Because I change code:

```
   var App=(
       <div>
           <SearchPage.Title />
           <SearchPage.Search searchType="Content"/>
       </div>
   );
```

Perhaps, it can get result.

So,I have another problem.

```
var MysearchPage=React.createClass({
        render:function(){
            return (
                <div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

***What is the difference between the above code and pure HTML tag ?*** Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The render function of `Mysearchpage` just returns an empty div, so you'll have to explicitly render all its component children:

```js
render:function(){
    return (
      <div>
          {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
```

> See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html